# Django deleting a model instance with no more related ForeignKey items in another model?

Tags: python, django

In the model below, when an Artist is deleted through Admin, it'll confirm and delete all related Songs.  However, when I delete a Song through Admin, I'd like to delete Artist as well if Artist has no more related items in Song.  Is there a model option for this in Admin?

How should this be done in a custom view not inside of ModelAdmin?

```
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Song (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mix = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: you might want to use `pre_delete` signal to delete the artist

Answer (score 0):

Could do this through the `delete` method of a `Song`.

`def delete(*args, **kwargs):
  artist = self.artist
  super(Song, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
  if artist.song_set.count() == 0:
    artist.delete()`

Or something similar.

Comment: No context as to why this was down-voted. If this rule is always the case for Song.delete, then this is a valid and straightforward approach. If this is only through Admin and not the general case, then I could see the problem with it.